# Расположение textarea в том же месте, что и td

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть таблица в phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При двойном щелчке на ячейку таблица принимает следующий вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать также со своей таблицей (чтобы при двойном щелчке на ячейке раскрывалось поле для редактирования)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hstyle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;   
}

.secondandmore {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#second {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.calltable tr td {
    /*border-spacing: 10px;*/
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;

    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);

}

.calltable {
    margin-top: 30px;
    /*border-spacing: 40px;*/
    /*border: 2px solid royalblue;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#btns {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#addoperator {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#addnewuser {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#addnewcall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

.addcall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#deleteoperator {
    border: 1px solid rgb(254, 0, 0);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(254, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;       
}

.checkboxitemuserlist, .checkboxitemuserlisttotalcost {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftmenu {
    flex: 1;
}

.tableblock {
    flex: 2;
}

.wrapperusers {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftmenuusers {
    flex: 1;
}

.tableblockusers {
    flex: 2;
}

#alllistoperators, #alllistusers {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#alllistoperators tr td{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    /*
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
    */

    border: 2px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);
    background-color: white;    
}

#alllistoperators thead tr th {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    
    border: 2px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);
    background-color: rgb(99, 106, 116);
    color: white;
}


#alllistusers tr td {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}


#userdurationcalltable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

#userdurationcalltable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}



.leftmenuoperators {
    flex: 1;
}

#operatorsdurationcalltable{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

#operatorsdurationcalltable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}


#stattable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#stattable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}

#calculation {
    text-align: right;
}

.elemcheckbox {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.elemuserlist, .elemoperatorlist {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.centeredblock {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.chooseperiod {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.chooseperiodbegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.chooseperiodend {
    display:  flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#beginlocaldate, #endlocaldate {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/*
#choosedatetimebegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

#chooseduration {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}
*/

#choosedatetimebegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

.labeldatetimebegin {
    width:  305px;
}

.datetimeinput {
    width: 100%-305px;
}

#chooseduration {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.duration {
    width: 424px;
}

.durationinput {
    width: 100%-424px;
}

#inuser {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#labelinuser {
    width: 310px;
}

#selectinuser {
    width: 100%-310px;
}

#outuser {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#labeloutuser {
    width: 310px;
}

#selectoutuser {
    width: 100%-310px;
}

.checkboxitemusertotalcost{
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.checkboxitemusernametotalcost {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="tableblock">
            <table id="alllistoperators">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th>
                        Оператор    
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Тариф
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
      </table>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы скрытое textarea имело те же координаты, что и td?

Comment: на js можешь это реализовать, в phpmyadmin в разметке есть скрытое textarea, когда кликаешь по ячейке, textarea подставляются нужные координаты и поле делается видимым.

Comment: @Jean-Claude я обновил вопрос.

Comment: js - вычисляешь координаты кликнутого td, подставляешь их в textarea

Comment: @Jean-Claude можете привести команды (команды, которые задают расположение textarea)?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/